# In Jmeter, how to run either of one Http request from 2 Https request samplers?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have 3 HTTP requests in total.  I need to run the 1st request every time. After 1st request is executed, I need to run request 2 or request 3.
Request 2 should run only for 25% of time and rest 75% is Request 3.

How do I achieve this scenario in Jmeter for single user.

Answer (score 1):

The buitl-in option is using 2 [Throughput Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

[image]

a little bit more handy solution is going for the [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter) plugin, this way you will avoid copying and pasting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a counter (from 1 to 4) and if clause.
Example:

- If Counter == 1 => execute Request 2, else (3,4,5) - skip executing of Request 2;
- If Counter == 3,4,5 => execute Request 3, else (1) - skip executing of Request 3.

But in this case you'll have the same requests executed every time. You have to think about some kind of randomization, but in that case sometimes some of the requests can be executed more frequent, sometimes not... It's up to your needs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).